# SQL 2 select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question about syntax of the code below. I'm trying to make 2 selects ,one of them is to calculate daily sales ,but without success.The error i got is

> ORA-00936: missing expression

```
SELECT
    sale_kol * prod_price AS total
FROM nalichni_produkti,sale_product
    (
        SELECT
            product.prod_name,
            n.prod_price,
            sale_product.sale_kol,
            klient.klient_name,
            sale.dates
        FROM
                 product
            INNER JOIN sale ON sale.sale_id = product.prod_id
            INNER JOIN klient ON klient.klient_id = sale.klient_klient_id
            INNER JOIN nalichni_produkti n ON n.product_prod_id = product.prod_id
            INNER JOIN sale_product ON sale_product.sale_sale_id = sale.sale_id
        WHERE
            sale.dates BETWEEN ( '&Data1' ) AND ( '&Data2' )
    ) 
WHERE
    nalichni_produkti.product_prod_id = sale_product.sale_sale_id;
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Is `sale_product` an actual table, or the name for the derived table?

Comment: You have subquery after `sale_product` that is not separated by comma. But never use tables in `FROM`, there's `JOIN` for this.

Comment: @jarlh yes it is actual table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted query is raising an exception because you are referencing a table (or database object) that doesn't exist: sale_product. The indirect cause of this is because you are using an implicit join (using commas in the `FROM` clause instead of `JOIN`). Joining nalichni_produkti to a subquery will work, but putting the alias for the subquery *before* the subquery makes the parser think that 'sale_product' is a second database object you are selecting - not the *alias* you're giving to your subquery.

Second, note that your initial query does not include sale.sale_id in the `SELECT` clause of sale_product. If you copied only the end of n1k9's code (not saying that this is what you did, but *if* you did), you may get an invalid identifier exception because sale_id is not in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

I rewite something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    sale_product_alias.sale_kol * sale_product_alias.prod_price AS total
FROM nalichni_produkti
JOIN (
        SELECT
            sale.sale_id,  -- (1)
            product.prod_name,
            n.prod_price,
            sale_product.sale_kol,
            klient.klient_name,
            sale.dates
        FROM product
            INNER JOIN sale ON sale.sale_id = product.prod_id
            INNER JOIN klient ON klient.klient_id = sale.klient_klient_id
            INNER JOIN nalichni_produkti n ON n.product_prod_id = product.prod_id
            INNER JOIN sale_product ON sale_product.sale_sale_id = sale.sale_id
        WHERE
            sale.dates BETWEEN ( '&Data1' ) AND ( '&Data2' )
    ) AS sale_product_alias ON nalichni_produkti.product_prod_id = sale_product_alias.sale_id;
```

where subquery has an alias `sale_product_alias`

Or without `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT
    sale_product_alias.sale_kol * sale_product_alias.prod_price AS total
FROM nalichni_produkti,
 (
        SELECT
            sale.sale_id,  -- (1)
            product.prod_name,
            n.prod_price,
            sale_product.sale_kol,
            klient.klient_name,
            sale.dates
        FROM product
            INNER JOIN sale ON sale.sale_id = product.prod_id
            INNER JOIN klient ON klient.klient_id = sale.klient_klient_id
            INNER JOIN nalichni_produkti n ON n.product_prod_id = product.prod_id
            INNER JOIN sale_product ON sale_product.sale_sale_id = sale.sale_id
        WHERE
            sale.dates BETWEEN ( '&Data1' ) AND ( '&Data2' )
    ) AS sale_product_alias
WHERE nalichni_produkti.product_prod_id = sale_product_alias.sale_id;
```

Note: (1) field to resolve `nalichni_produkti.product_prod_id = sale_product_alias.sale_id` expression.

Comment: thanks , just test it and there is error "SALE_PRODUCT_ALIAS"."SALE_SALE_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: Try to remove `_alias`

Comment: removed it and the same error, actually if i separate the code everything works fine

Comment: @Denis with or without `JOIN`?

Comment: with join working just fine , the problem is that i cant make them in one select query

Comment: thanks for your time helping me ,i just write the query in new structure and it worked